# How to check the server access using WMI?

Tags: wmi, wmi-query

I have used WMI to get the remote server disk space report using widows service.
Im getting Access Denied exception, can any one suggest how to check the server access before it got exception.

I need to check the server access before getting the disk space.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around that I have added valid network accounts under User Accounts > Manage Your Network Passwords.